# Replace 36" range with 30"

Tags: kitchens, range

My house came with a lovely 36" Viking propane range that's now 20 years old, and starting to die. Replacing it would be expensive. Exorbitantly, and infeasibly expensive.

Replacement 36" ranges are pretty pricy - even the low-end ones, and I could put in a very high end 30" for less than the cheapest 36".

But - what to do about that extra 6", and are there any other issues I'm missing? The range is in the middle of the counter, so I can't just ignore the gap.

Comment: Be sure and try to sell the old Viking.  Someone will want it - don't just give it away to the appliance haul off people.  But, back to the question - what type of counter top do you have and what's the cabinet construction (hint, both can be answered with a picture).

Comment: They'll want it, *and how!* Great appliances like that are repairable.  The people will buy them, overhaul them and flip them.  They're not just throwaway appliances like so many things these days.

Comment: Agreed with both comments. Viking ranges are really pretty simple, generally. They have had reliability problems.   I have a 48" double oven and had problems with the igniters failing.  I found some after market (different brand) igniters that have done much better than the stock Viking replacements.  I have had some "in stock" for years, just in case if the igniter fails at Thanksgiving time! ...which happened!  :-(  But I have not had to use them because the others last and last.   I think your least expensive alternative is to do major maint on your current range.

Comment: Why not fix it?

Comment: My wife has a 30" range but would like to have a 36" range. Cooking is much better with the larger range, the cooking pans fit better.